# Regex match between two arrays of strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, match

I have two arrays

```
sentences_ary = ['This is foo', 'bob is cool'] 

words_ary = ['foo', 'lol', 'something']
```

I want to check if any element from `sentences_ary` matched any word from `words_ary`.

I'm able to check for one work, but could not do it with `word_ary`.

```
#This is working
['This is foo', 'bob is cool'].any? { |s| s.match(/foo/)}
```

But I'm not able to make it work with ary of ary regex. I'm always getting true from this:

```
# This is not working    
['This is foo', 'bob is cool'].any? { |s| ['foo', 'lol', 'something'].any? { |w| w.match(/s/) } }
```

I'm using this in the `if` condition.

Comment: What about `s.match(w)`?

Comment: That worked!! write it in answer I will accept it.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to use a regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RegexpTrie](https://github.com/gfx/ruby-regexp_trie) improves this:

```
require 'regexp_trie'

sentences_ary = ['This is foo', 'This is foolish', 'bob is cool', 'foo bar', 'bar foo']
words_ary = ['foo', 'lol', 'something']

words_regex = /\b(?:#{RegexpTrie.union(words_ary, option: Regexp::IGNORECASE).source})\b/i
# => /\b(?:(?:foo|lol|something))\b/i

sentences_ary.any?{ |s| s[words_regex] } # => true
sentences_ary.find{ |s| s[words_regex] } # => "This is foo"
sentences_ary.select{ |s| s[words_regex] } # => ["This is foo", "foo bar", "bar foo"]
```

---

You have to be careful how you construct your regex pattern, otherwise you can get false-positive hits. That can be a difficult bug to track down.

```
sentences_ary = ['This is foo', 'This is foolish', 'bob is cool', 'foo bar', 'bar foo']
words_ary = ['foo', 'lol', 'something']
words_regex = /\b(?:#{ Regexp.union(words_ary).source })\b/ # => /\b(?:foo|lol|something)\b/
sentences_ary.any?{ |s| s[words_regex] } # => true
sentences_ary.find{ |s| s[words_regex] } # => "This is foo"
sentences_ary.select{ |s| s[words_regex] } # => ["This is foo", "foo bar", "bar foo"]
```

The `/\b(?:foo|lol|something)\b/` pattern that is generated is smart enough to look for word-boundaries, which will find words, not just sub-strings.

Also, notice the use of [`source`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Regexp.html#method-i-source). This is very important because its absence can lead to a very hard to locate bug. Compare these two regexp:

```
/#{ Regexp.union(words_ary).source }/ # => /foo|lol|something/
/#{ Regexp.union(words_ary) }/        # => /(?-mix:foo|lol|something)/
```

Notice how the second one has the embedded flags `(?-mix:...)`. They change the flags for the enclosed pattern, *inside* the surrounding pattern. It's possible to have that inner pattern behave differently than the surrounding one resulting in a black hole sucking in results you don't expect.

Even [the Regexp `union` documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Regexp.html) shows the situation but doesn't mention why it can be bad:

```
Regexp.union(/dogs/, /cats/i)        #=> /(?-mix:dogs)|(?i-mx:cats)/
```

Notice that in this case, both patterns have different flags. On our team we use `union` often, but I'm always careful to look to see how it's being used during peer reviews. I got bit by this once, and it was tough figuring out what was wrong, so I am very sensitive to it. Though `union` takes patterns, as in the example, I recommend not using them and instead use an array of words or the pattern as a string, to avoid those pesky flags sneaking in there. There's a time and place for them, but knowing about this allows us to control when they get used.

Read through [the Regexp documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Regexp.html) multiple times, as there's a lot to learn and it will be overwhelming the first several passes through it.

And, for extra-credit, read:

- "[Ruby gsub / regex with several arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569214/ruby-gsub-regex-with-several-arguments/13570402#13570402)"
- "[Is there an efficient way to perform hundreds of text substitutions in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395236/is-there-an-efficient-way-to-perform-hundreds-of-text-substitutions-in-ruby/5395777#5395777)"

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Regexp.union`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Regexp.html#method-c-union) and [`Enumerable#grep`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep):

```
sentences_ary.grep(Regexp.union(words_ary))
#=> ["This is foo"]
```

Comment: This is more cleaner than my code. This is awesome.

Comment: Be careful using `Regexp.union`. The resulting pattern will match words, and sub-strings embedded in words.

Comment: Yeah. I verified it. I really want this ans. I'm using spaces in words_ary if substring is not needed. Thanks for info @theTinMan

Comment: Using spaces isn't the way to go if a word could occur at the start or end of a string, or have punctuation before or after it.

Comment: I love your answer (+1!), because I can see many uses for it in other applications, but, alas, I don't think it's quite right here, for it doesn't deal with punctuation (as @theTinMan mentioned) or case. You could modify it to make it more robust, but then it would be prosiac.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
def good_sentences(sentences_ary, words_ary)
  sentences_ary.select do |s|
    (s.downcase.gsub(/[^a-z\s]/,'').split & words_ary).any?
  end
end
```

For the example:

```
sentences_ary = ['This is foo', 'bob is cool']
words_ary = ['foo', 'lol', 'something']

good_sentences(sentences_ary, words_ary)
  #=> ["This is foo"]
```

For a case case:

```
words_ary = ['this', 'lol', 'something']
  #=> ["This is foo"]
good_sentences(sentences_ary, words_ary)
  #=> ["This is foo"]
```

For a punctuation case:

```
sentences_ary = ['This is Foo!', 'bob is very "cool" indeed!']
words_ary = ['foo', 'lol', 'cool']
good_sentences(sentences_ary, words_ary)
  #=> ["This is Foo!", "bob is very \"cool\" indeed!"]
```